# Use accessor syntax in cython for cpp classes

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython, accessor

If I have a class defined as follows in C++

```
class sample
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    sample()
    {
        data=0;
    }

    int get_data()
    {
        return data;
    }

    void set_data(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
};
```

and I want to expose it to cython code using:

```
cdef extern from "sample.cpp":
    cdef cppclass sample:
        sample() except +
        int get_data()
        void set_data(int n)
```

Is there a way to expose the getter and setter in that class in such a way that they can then be used in cython using syntax such as:

```
a = obj.data
```

instead of

```
a = obj.get_data()
```

I know it is possible to do that by wrapping the class in cython defined class, but I would like to avoid that avoid that overhead.

Maybe I am asking for too much.

Comment: would it be ok to add the wrap in the c++ code?

Comment: You mean using boost.python? That would amount in wrapping the original class as well as a python object I presume. I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: no I mean implementing a `obj.data` already in the c++ class

Comment: on the other hand, why not simply make `data` public?

Comment: Not sure to understand. I can make the data field public and expose it to cython. But I then lose the benefit of controlling what happens when I set a value, which is the point of writing explicitly accessors.

Comment: "Maybe I am asking for too much." - from a Cython point of view: yes. All Cython really aims to do if let you access the c++ class using its c++ interface. You could obviously write a `cdef class` wrapper with properties though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know cython, so I cannot say if the following will be fine for cython. However, my strategy would be to implement access via `s.data` already in the C++ code to keep the bindings slim and straightforward.

C++ has no attributes, but one can emulate them:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,typename M,M (T::*getter)(),void (T::*setter)(M)>
struct Attribute {
    T* parent;
    Attribute(T* parent) : parent(parent){}
    operator M() const {
        return (parent->*getter)();
    }
    void operator=(const M& m){
        (parent->*setter)(m);
    }

};

class sample
{
private:
    int data_;
public:

    sample()
    {
        data_=0;
    }    

    int get_data()
    {
        return data_;
    }

    void set_data(int data_)
    {
        this->data_ = data_;
    }
    Attribute<sample,int,&sample::get_data,&sample::set_data> data{this};
};

int main() {
    sample s;
    s.data = 42;
    std::cout << s.data;
}
```

Output is `42`. Note that I had to assume a `int` parameter for the setter. To enable also `const int&` a bit more will be needed.

Comment: I suspect this would work with Cython - you'd just tell Cython that `sample` contains an integer called `data`, and it'd generate valid c++ code. (Unless you tried to take a pointer to data or something, which might end in disaster.)

Comment: @idclev 463035818 Wow this looks like very high flying C++ to me. Thanks! It does the job in C++.

Comment: @DavidW As you suggested, it plugs right with cython. I'll detail the solution above. Many thanks !

Comment: @user2116486 consider to post your solution as answer. Solutions do not belong to questions. Editing an answer into a question makes the question harder to read for future readers

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of the sample c++ class in the accepted response above by @idclev 463035818, and copied here for convenience:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,typename M,M (T::*getter)(),void (T::*setter)(M)>
struct Attribute {
    T* parent;
    Attribute(T* parent) : parent(parent){}
    operator M() const {
        return (parent->*getter)();
    }
    void operator=(const M& m){
        (parent->*setter)(m);
    }

};

class sample
{
private:
    int data_;
public:

    sample()
    {
        data_=0;
    }    

    int get_data()
    {
        return data_;
    }

    void set_data(int data_)
    {
        this->data_ = data_;
    }
    Attribute<sample,int,&sample::get_data,&sample::set_data> data{this};
};
```

I tested declaring that C++ class in cython with a flat public property, and ... it works! This does the job.

```
cdef extern from "sample.cpp":
    cdef cppclass sample:
        sample() except +
        int data
```

Testing that and instrumenting the accessors in the example shows that the accessors are properly called.

Many thanks to everyone! That was *very* helpful.